# WPF: Property binding doesn't update at run-time

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, combobox, telerik

I need your help.
I use MVVM design pattern in my application. I have a combobox inside my datagrid:

```
<telerik:RadGridView AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="rgvData" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
        <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
            <telerik:GridViewColumn  Header="Department">
                <telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <telerik:RadComboBox
                                            ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},Path=DataContext.Departments}"
                                            SelectedValue="{Binding DEP_LINK,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                            SelectedValuePath="LINK"
                                            DisplayMemberPath="TITLE">
                        </telerik:RadComboBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </telerik:GridViewColumn>
        </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
    </telerik:RadGridView>
```

Data is an ObservableCollection of DATA. 
Departments is an ObservableCollection of DEPARTMENTS.
Both of classes are entities from SQL Server.

Now I want the combobox to be colored based on IsDepartmentUsed property of DATA class. Here is a style for that:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox.Style>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type telerik:RadComboBox}">
       <Style.Triggers>
           <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsDepartmentUsed}" Value="False">
               <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
           </DataTrigger>
           <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsDepartmentUsed}" Value="True">
               <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
           </DataTrigger>
       </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>
</telerik:RadComboBox.Style>
```

It works fine when the window is just opened. But if I change a value of the combobox, it doesn't change color!

Here how the IsDepartmentUsed property looks like:

```
public partial class DATA
{
    public bool IsDepartmentUsed
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.DEPARTMENTS.ISUSED != null)
            {
                return Convert.ToBoolean(this.DEPARTMENTS.ISUSED);
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your UI doesn't know that the property has changed, so does not know it needs to update. You need to trigger the `PropertyChanged` event handler for `IsDepartmentUsed` whenever the `IsUsed` property changes.

It sounds like you're using something like Entity Framework to generate your Models, so if I've understood your data hierarchy correctly, your partial `Data` class can attach a `CollectionChanged` event handler to the `Departments` collection, which adds or removes a `PropertyChange` event handler to the `Department` classes inside it, which in turn raises a change notification for `IsDepartmentUsed` anytime the `IsUsed` property changes.

```
void Data()
{
    this.Departments.CollectionChanged += Departments_CollectionChanged;
}

void Departments_CollectionChanged (object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewItems != null)
    {
        foreach(Department item in e.NewItems)
            item.PropertyChanged += Department_PropertyChanged;
    }
    if (e.OldItems != null)
    {
        foreach(Department item in e.OldItems)
            item.PropertyChanged -= Department_PropertyChanged;
    }
}

void Department_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "IsUsed")
        RaisePropertyChanged("IsDepartmentUsed");
}
```

I am assuming here that your `Department` class implements [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx) since you are using it for your `Model` layer.

(Your code is a bit hard to follow since you say `DEPARTMENTS` is an `ObservableCollection`, however an `ObservableCollection` does not have an `ISUSED` property such as you have in your C# code, so I may have misunderstood your data hierarchy. The same concept should apply though - attach something to the `PropertyChanged` event of the class, which raises the `PropertyChanged` notification for `IsDepartmentUsed` whenever `IsUsed` changes)

Comment: Thanks, Rachel! This is pretty close to what I want. Some points: **DEPARTMENTS** is the autogenerated entity. Departments is the **ObservableCollection<DEPARTMENTS>**. Same thing with **DATA**. So **DATA** class doesn't have **ObservableCollection<DEPARTMENTS>**, but has **DEPARTMENTS** class instead. I've added: public void UpdateIsDepartmentUsedProperty() { OnPropertyChanged("IsDepartmentUsed"); } in **DATA** class. If I call it from ViewModel everything work just fine and the property updates successfully. But I think it some kind of 'dirty' code.